# Ubuntu buttons theme won't change

Tags: themes

When I try any theme other than Ambiance or Equinox buttons (only when maximized)are from these two themes. I can't change them to be from my current theme :/ Is there any solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately not every themes have full unity/global-menu support. You can search for unity themes instead of simple gtk-themes. You can find often adapted version of popular gtk themes.